# Retrieving remaining time from python timer

Tags: python, timer, python-multithreading, elapsedtime

Looking for simple approach to obtaining remaining and elapsed time from python timer. Currently have (based on github source for threading.Timer and previous post):

```
import threading
import time

class CountdownTimer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, args=None, kwargs=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.args = args if args is not None else []
        self.kwargs = kwargs if kwargs is not None else {}
        self.finished = Event()
        self.started_at = None

    def cancel(self):
        self.finished.set()

    def elapsed(self):
        return time.time() - self.started_at

    def remaining(self):
        return self.interval - self.elapsed()

    def run(self):
        self.started_at = time.time()
        self.finished.wait(self.interval)
        if not self.finished.is_set():
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        self.finished.set()
```

Does this look reasonably effective (do not need accuracy in excess of what threading.Timer currently provides)?

Comment: yes it's a good approach. It all depends on your need. Generally, if I want to monitore time through my programs, I simply use `time.time()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**perf_counter()**

```
import time

start = time.perf_counter()
time.sleep(2)
finish = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} second(s)')
```

**Advantages of perf_counter() :**

1. `perf_counter()` will give you more precise value than `time.clock()` function .
2. From Python3.8 `time.clock()` function will be deleted and `perf_counter` will be used.
3. We can calculate float and integer both values of time in seconds and nanoseconds.

Comment: Thank you, that is simple and would give higher precision.

Comment: Went with this approach as class approach was overkill for my purpose, and as @xaander1 mentions, solution provides additional resolution. Thanks again!